# Passing function through props in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here are two components one is Home.js and other is BlogList.js
I am passing handleDelete() as a prop into BlogList and using it as a function in Home.js.

**Home.js**

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import BlogList from './Bloglist';

const Home = () => {
    const handleDelete = (id) =>{
        console.log(id);
    }

    const [blogs ,setBlogs] = useState([
    { title: 'My new website', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'mario', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Welcome party!', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'Akks', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Web dev top tips', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'mario', id: 3 }
    ])
    
    return ( 
<div className="home">
<BlogList blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs"/>  
<BlogList blogs={blogs.filter((blog)=>blog.author==="mario")} handleDelete={handleDelete}/>
</div>
     );
}
 
export default Home;
```

**blogList.js**

```
const BlogList = ({blogs,title,handleDelete}) => {
    return ( 
        <div className="blog-list">
            <h2> {title} </h2>
            {blogs.map(b=>(
                <div className="blog-preview" key={b.id}>
                    <h2>{b.title}</h2>
                    <p>written by {b.author}</p>
                    <button onClick={()=> handleDelete(b.id)}></button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default BlogList;
```

But it is showing error that `handleDelete is not a function`

Comment: You are not passing handleDelete to first BlogList component you returned.

Comment: Yes, true, first BlogList doesn't have a reference to handleDelete function, so you have to check if its undefined before even calling it.

Comment: Maybe good way to solve this is to check if function is passed and execute it : 
<button onClick={handleDelete && ()=> handleDelete(b.id)}></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your `handleDelete` is optional prop in `BlogList` component, you should first check if it's defined when passing it as onClick handler to button:

```
<button onClick={handleDelete ? () => handleDelete(b.id) : undefined}></button>
```

Also, you should check `prop-types` package on NPM or at least basic typescript to avoid similar errors in future.